# append a row on a given "id",but its not appending

Tags: javascript, html

I am appending a row on a given "id" after entering the input field but it's not appending.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var obj = "<tr><td>" + document.getElementById("name").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("num").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("address").value + "</td></tr>";
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = obj;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></td>

    <td>Age:<input type="number" id="num"></td>

    <td>Address:<input type="text" id="address"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="click on me"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="table">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: You are not appending, you are overwriting the HTML of the `<tbody>.` This would be appending -> `document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += obj;`

Comment: also 3 n's `.innnerHTML` is invalid syntax

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : you have several typo:

- You write "innnnerHtml" (3n) instead of "innerHtml"
- By writing `innerHtml = obj` you replace all html inside the selected div (the table in your case) you must use "+="

You use `innerHtml`property instead of `append`function.

```js
function myfunction(){
var obj = "<tr><td>" + document.getElementById("name").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("num").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("address").value + "</td></tr>";
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += obj;
}


// an other way to do it
function myfunction2() {

  var line = document.createElement("tr");
  
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.append(document.getElementById("name").value);
  
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.append(document.getElementById("num").value);
  
  var td3 = document.createElement("td");
  td3.append(document.getElementById("address").value);
  
  line.append(td1);
  line.append(td2);
  line.append(td3);
  
  document.getElementById("table").append(line)


}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></td>

    <td>Age:<input type="number" id="num"></td>

    <td>Address:<input type="text" id="address"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="click on me"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction2()" value="other way"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="table">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem

Comment: you're welcome, please read the last update of the answer :) mark it as resolved if it does

Answer (score 1):

It's better to call [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Using `appendChild` adds a new DOM element to the end of the parent node, while `innerHTML` takes the existing DOM content of the parent node, work with it as string, and overwrite the existing elements of the parent node with DOM generated elements from that string.

But, in Javascript we have a couple of functions like [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) that helps you even more. See the example:

```js
function myfunction() {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value,
      num = document.getElementById("num").value,
      address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table");
    addRow(tbody, name, num, address);
}

function addRow(tbody, name, num, address){
  var row = tbody.insertRow();
  addCell(row, name, 0);
  addCell(row, num, 1);
  addCell(row, address, 2);
}

function addCell(row, cellText, index){
  var cell = row.insertCell(index);
  cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellText));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></td>

    <td>Age:<input type="number" id="num"></td>

    <td>Address:<input type="text" id="address"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="click on me"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="table">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: In essence; the OP should use the appropriate API tools for managing table, mainly covered in this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) which is far more user friendly than using `.innerHTML += ...` (of which is a horror) or `.appendChild` with table rows.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

html code

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></td>

    <td>Age:<input type="number" id="num"></td>

    <td>Address:<input type="text" id="address"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="click on me"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody >

  </tbody>

</table>
```

javascript  function

```
    function myfunction() {
                var obj = "<tr><td>Name:" + document.getElementById("name").value + "</td><td>Age: " + document.getElementById("num").value + "</td><td>Address:" + document.getElementById("address").value + "</td></tr>";

               $('#table tbody').append(obj);
             // document.getElementById("table").innnerHTML = obj;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . It will helps you.

```
function myfunction() {
  var obj = "<tr><td>" + document.getElementById("name").value + "</td><td>" + 
  document.getElementById("num").value + "</td><td>" + 
  document.getElementById("address").value + "</td></tr>";
  table.innerHTML  = obj;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Use this and watch out for the following:**

1. Your table structure.
2. Typo in innerHTML
3. Your script was meant to overwrite not append.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var obj = "<tr><td>" + document.getElementById("name").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("num").value + "</td><td>" + document.getElementById("address").value + "</td></tr>";
  document.getElementById("table").innerHTML += obj;

  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table">

  <tr>

    <td>Name: <input type="text" id="name"></td>

    <td>Age:<input type="number" id="num"></td>

    <td>Address:<input type="text" id="address"></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="click on me"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Already answered in full in the two comments 15 minutes ago. AND in another identical answer